# Regex pattern for testing url paths

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with writing a regular expression for an apache configuration file. To the point:

If an url looks like this:`http://somedomain.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/wp-color-    frames/complete/b5c43baac3fb1ef5f6aa314407a7353e.jpg`

The test should pass if the url contains something like:
`/wp-color-frames/complete/[random alphanumeric].jpg`

How to write this kind of regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex such as `/\/wp-color-frames\/complete\/[a-fA-F0-9]+\.jpg$/` should work completely fine.

Autopsy:

- `\/wp-color-frames\/complete\/` the literal string `/wp-color-frames/complete/` with the slashes escaped. (**NOTE**: You do not need to escape the slashes when used in `.htaccess`)
- `[a-fA-F0-9]+` the characters from a-f both lower and upper case and digits from 0 to 9 repeated 1 or more times
- `\.jpg` the literal string `.jpg` (you have to escape the `.` as it otherwise means "any character". (**NOTE**: You still need to escape the `.` in `.htaccess`)
- `$` - the end of the string must be here (else it'd also match `abc123.jpg.php`)

Comment: @MaciejAndrzej I'm glad it worked for you - just remember the limits. This will also match `http://somedomain.com/foo/wp-color-frames/complete/abc123.jpg` and `http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/wp-color-frames/complete/abc123.jpg` etc. :)